# Chef notifies when command fails

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

```
execute "pear7 install mail" do
    command "pear7 install mail"
    action :nothing
end

bash "Check if pear/mail was not installed" do
    command "! (pear7 info pear/mail > /dev/null 2>&1)"
    notifies :run,"execute[pear7 install mail]", :immediately
end
```

`pear7 info pear/mail` returns 0 exit code when package is installed and 1 when it doesn't exist. I would like to notify first action only in the second case, that's why I added negative on the beginning of command.

The thing is that first block is executed always. How can I achieve result when notification is send only if the package is not installed?

I can't use `only_if` or `not_if` guards, because I have to run other commands which will make notifications to the same job.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how notifications work. They fire if the resource is considered "updated". For `execute`, it is considered updated if the command runs. The return code is not looked at for notification purposes at all. Despite saying you can't, the correct answer is probably `not_if`/`only_if` guards, otherwise you'll need some custom resource stuffs and to use `shell_out()` and manually sequence things.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I dealt with it. Unfortunately I couldn't avoid guards.

```
execute "pear7 install mail" do
    command "pear7 install mail"
    action :nothing
end

Chef::Resource::Bash.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::ShellOut)

bash "Check if pear/mail was not installed" do
    command ":"
    only_if { shell_out("pear7 info pear/mail > /dev/null 2>&1").exitstatus != 0 }
    notifies :run,"execute[pear7 install mail]", :immediately
end
```

Command which is only a colon means "do nothing". It's required to add a guard.

Comment: That is the same as `not_if "pear7 info pear/mail"`. And you don't need a notification, just put the guard on the `execute` resource.

Comment: I'm going to add additional checks which should fire installation. That's why I chosen notifiers to be used instead of one guard.

Comment: You can have multiple guards on a single resource. If you do stick with the funky notification chaining for some reason, use a `ruby_block` resource with `block { }`, it will be faster and less error prone when editing :)

Comment: How can I have multiple guards which works as OR statement instead of AND?